# How to import variables from a hash as global variables?

Tags: perl

In connection with some unit tests I found that it would be nice to
be able to import a set of global variables into the current package from a predeclared hash. After being imported, they should not have to be qualified by the package name like `$main::var1`, but instead simply as `$var1`.

I found that they then had to be predeclared with `our`, but that was not possible to do programmatically for example using `eval '$::var1=3; our $var1'` will only declare `$var1` in the scope of `eval`..

eventually I found that I could use the `vars` pragma:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
    my %test_vars = ( var1 => 3, var2 => 1 );
    my @names;
    for my $key (keys %test_vars) {
        my $temp = $test_vars{$key};
        no strict 'refs';
        *{"main\::$key"} = \$temp;
        push @names, "\$$key";
    }
    use vars @names;
}

#our $var1;
say $var1;
```

but this gives error:

```
Variable "$var1" is not imported at ./p.pl line 22.
Global symbol "$var1" requires explicit package name at ./p.pl line 22.
Execution of ./p.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

If I instead replace `use vars @names;` with the hardcoded names `use vars qw($var1 $var2);` it works fine..

Comment: Well you can get a little closer: `$main::var1` can also be referred to as `$::var1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use NAME LIST
```

is virtually the same as

```
BEGIN {
   require NAME;
   import NAME LIST;
}
```

and BEGIN blocks are executed as soon as they are compiled. As such, you're passing an empty list to vars.pm's `import`.

```
$ perl -E'
   BEGIN {
      say "Outer BEGIN";
      my @names = "abc";
      BEGIN { say "Inner BEGIN <<@names>>"; }
   }
'
Inner BEGIN <<>>
Outer BEGIN
```

Fix:

```
use vars qw( );

BEGIN {
   my %test_vars = ( var1 => 3, var2 => 1 );

   for my $name (keys(%test_vars)) {
      no strict qw( refs );
      *$name = \( $test_vars{$name} );
   }

   vars->import(map "\$$_", keys(%test_vars));
}
```

This could also be written as follows:

```
BEGIN {
   package AppVars;

   use Export qw( import );

   my %test_vars = ( var1 => 3, var2 => 1 );

   our @EXPORT = map "\$$_", keys(%test_vars);

   for my $name (keys(%test_vars)) {
      no strict qw( refs );
      *$name = \( $test_vars{$name} );
   }

   $INC{"AppVars.pm"} = 1;
}

use AppVars;
```

The key to declaring a variable is to create it in a different namespace than the one from which it will be accessed. As such, you could also use the following:

```
BEGIN {
   package initialized_vars;

   sub import {
      shift;
      my %hash = @_;
      my $pkg = caller;

      for my $name (keys(%hash)) {
         no strict qw( refs );
         *{$pkg.'::'.$name} = \( $hash{$name} );
      }
   }

   $INC{"initialized_vars.pm"} = 1;
}

use initialized_vars ( var1 => 3, var2 => 1 );
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know why it is necessary to define it from another namespace.. if I do it in `main` I have to use `our` but if I do it from another it is not necessary to predeclare it with `our` in `main`. How does this make sense?

Comment: Also I would like the global variables not to be aliases into the hash. So if I later change `$var1 = 4` in main, `$var1` should not also change in another package at the same time.. that is why I used the `my $temp = $test_vars{$name}` to create a new variable in each name space. If I use `*$name = \( $test_vars{$name} );` as you propose, I would get an alias, right?

Comment: It makes sense. Otherwise, `use Config qw( %Config );` would create a hash you couldn't use

Comment: Re "`$var1` should not also change in another package at the same time", I don't know what you mean. The variable is only placed into one package. /// If you plan to modify the code to export the vars into multiple packages, I can't help but feel you'd have a bad design.

Comment: Sorry, the question was not very clear.. I also have a the feeling this is not an ideal design.. I was thinking of having `%test_vars` as a fixed hash and populate it into both `main` and another package created at runtime for testing.. maybe it will be easier to just create a the whole package in temp directory and then `require` it from there at run time?